# No result from EventLogFile for Event Type = ReportExport

Tags: rest-api, reporting

I am sure that we are exporting reports but there are no result when I use this query:

```
SELECT Id,EventType,LogDate,LogFileLength,LogFile FROM EventLogFile WHERE EventType ='ReportExport'
```

I also tried https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/ but I didnt get any results there. 
We want to get history of reports that has been exported from our org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Event Monitoring for that Report Export event is not activated at your org.

For more information, refer [Enable Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339868&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: thanks for the reply. It looks like we have to purchase this addon. I was wondering if it would be possible to extract historical data once its activated?

Comment: The day you will activate the event, from that day those events will be monitored, it will not bring historical data before monitoring date